# Python - Gtk.TreeView with CheckBox

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, gtk, gtktreeview

I need to store items in a Gtk TreeView and when interacting with this TreeView, the user will can select one or more items in the list.

Because I'm new to GTK, I managed to populate the treeview and display a checkbox as the code below shows. But when I try to select, nothing happens and I do not know how to make this possible.

**This is my Code:**

```
# the column is created
renderer_products = gtk.CellRendererText()
column_products = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Products", renderer_products, text=0)
# and it is appended to the treeview
view.append_column(column_products)

# the column checkbox is created
renderer_checkbox = gtk.CellRendererToggle()
column_checkbox = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Selected", renderer_checkbox, text=0)
# and it is appended to the treeview
view.append_column(column_checkbox)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to select the whole row and something happen:

   ```
   #double click or not double click use
   Gtk.TreeView.set_activate_on_single_click (bool)
   #connect the treeview
   treeview.connect ("row-activated", on_row_activate)
   #inside the callback
   def on_row_activate (treeview, path, column):
       model = treeview.get_model ()
       iter  = treeview.get_iter (path)
       yourdata = model[iter][model_index]
       #do whatever with yourdata
   ```
2. If you want when you click the toggle and something happen:

   ```
   #connect the renderer
   renderer_checkbox.connect ("toggled", on_selected_toggled)
   #inside the callback
   def on_selected_toggled (renderer, path):
       #modify the model or get the value or whatever
   ```

Comment: Thanks, luciomrx. But your second tip does not solve. The signal "toggled" not exists in GetTreeViewColumn.

Comment: its not a Gtk.TreeView signal, its Gtk.CellRendererToggle